# Opencart Module Interal Error

Tags: php, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I've started creating a simple 'popular products' module for Opencart 2.3 just to get to grips with how to create modules in Opencart.

I'm having an issue where when I click to install the module from the extensions section in the backend I'm faced with an internal error page, some of my logic must be incorrect but I'm not all that sure where I'm going wrong. I was wondering whether anyone would be able to point out where my issues lie?

The module was intended just to be used on the default theme. I have labelled what files are what at the top commented out:

ADMIN FILES:

ADMIN CONTROLLER FILE

```
<!-- ADMIN CONTROLLER FILE -->

<?php
class ControllerModulePopular extends Controller {
  private $error = array();

  public function index() {
    $this->load->language('extension/module/popular');
    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));
    $this->load->model('extension/module');

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
      if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
        $this->model_extension_module->addModule('popular', $this->request->post);
      } else {
        $this->model_extension_module->editModule($this->request->get['module_id'], $this->request->post);
      }

      $this->cache->delete('product');
      $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
      $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&type=module', true));
    }

    $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
    $data['text_edit'] = $this->language->get('text_edit');
    $data['text_enabled'] = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
    $data['text_disabled'] = $this->language->get('text_disabled');

    $data['entry_name'] = $this->language->get('entry_name');
    $data['entry_limit'] = $this->language->get('entry_limit');
    $data['entry_width'] = $this->language->get('entry_width');
    $data['entry_height'] = $this->language->get('entry_height');
    $data['entry_status'] = $this->language->get('entry_status');

    $data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('button_save');
    $data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');

    if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
      $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
    } else {
      $data['error_warning'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['name'])) {
      $data['error_name'] = $this->error['name'];
    } else {
      $data['error_name'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['width'])) {
      $data['error_width'] = $this->error['width'];
    } else {
      $data['error_width'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['autoplay'])) {
      $data['error_autoplay'] = $this->error['autoplay'];
    } else {
      $data['error_autoplay'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['height'])) {
      $data['error_height'] = $this->error['height'];
    } else {
      $data['error_height'] = '';
    }


    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
      'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
      'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true)
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
      'text' => $this->language->get('text_module'),
      'href' => $this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&type=module', true)
    );

    if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
      $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('extension/module/popular', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true)
      );
    } else {
      $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('extension/module/popular', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&module_id=' . $this->request->get['module_id'], true)
      );
    }

    if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
      $data['action'] = $this->url->link('extension/module/popular', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true);
    } else {
      $data['action'] = $this->url->link('extension/module/popular', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&module_id=' . $this->request->get['module_id'], true);
    }

    $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&type=module', true);

    if (isset($this->request->get['module_id']) && ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')) {
      $module_info = $this->model_extension_module->getModule($this->request->get['module_id']);
    }

    $data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];

    if (isset($this->request->post['name'])) {
      $data['name'] = $this->request->post['name'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
      $data['name'] = $module_info['name'];
    } else {
      $data['name'] = '';
    }

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $data['products'] = array();

    if (isset($this->request->post['product'])) {
      $products = $this->request->post['product'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
      $products = $module_info['product'];
    } else {
      $products = array();
    }

    foreach ($products as $product_id) {
      $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

      if ($product_info) {
        $data['products'][] = array(
          'product_id' => $product_info['product_id'],
          'name'       => $product_info['name']
        );
      }
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['limit'])) {
      $data['limit'] = $this->request->post['limit'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
      $data['limit'] = $module_info['limit'];
    } else {
      $data['limit'] = 5;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['width'])) {
      $data['width'] = $this->request->post['width'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
      $data['width'] = $module_info['width'];
    } else {
      $data['width'] = 360;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['height'])) {
      $data['height'] = $this->request->post['height'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
      $data['height'] = $module_info['height'];
    } else {
      $data['height'] = 360;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['autoplay'])) {
      $data['autoplay'] = $this->request->post['autoplay'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
      $data['autoplay'] = $module_info['autoplay'];
    } else {
      $data['autoplay'] = 5000;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['status'])) {
      $data['status'] = $this->request->post['status'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
      $data['status'] = $module_info['status'];
    } else {
      $data['status'] = '';
    }



    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
    $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/module/popular.tpl', $data));
  }

  protected function validate() {
    if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'extension/module/popular')) {
      $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
    }

    if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) > 64)) {
      $this->error['name'] = $this->language->get('error_name');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['width']) {
      $this->error['width'] = $this->language->get('error_width');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['height']) {
      $this->error['height'] = $this->language->get('error_height');
    }


    return !$this->error;
  }
}
```

ADMIN LANGUAGE FILE

```
<!-- ADMIN LANGUAGE FILE -->

<?php
// Heading
$_['heading_title']    = 'Popular Products';

// Text
$_['text_module']      = 'Modules';
$_['text_success']     = 'Success: You have modified module "Popular Products"!';
$_['text_edit']        = 'Edit Popular Products Module';

// Entry
$_['entry_name']       = 'Module Name';
$_['entry_limit']      = 'Limit';
$_['entry_width']      = 'Width';
$_['entry_height']     = 'Height';
$_['entry_status']     = 'Status';

// Error
$_['error_permission']  = 'Warning: You do not have permission to modify module "Popular Products"!';
$_['error_width']       = 'Width required!';
$_['error_height']      = 'Height required!';
```

ADMIN VIEW FILE

```
<!-- ADMIN VIEW FILE -->

<?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?>
<div id="content">
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" form="form-popular" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_save; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
        <a href="<?php echo $cancel; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_cancel; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a></div>
      <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> <?php echo $error_warning; ?>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <?php echo $text_edit; ?></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-popular" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-name"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_name; ?>" id="input-name" class="form-control" />
              <?php if ($error_name) { ?>
              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_name; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-limit"><?php echo $entry_limit; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="limit" value="<?php echo $limit; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_limit; ?>" id="input-limit" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-width"><?php echo $entry_width; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="width" value="<?php echo $width; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_width; ?>" id="input-width" class="form-control" />
              <?php if ($error_width) { ?>
              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_width; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-height"><?php echo $entry_height; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="height" value="<?php echo $height; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_height; ?>" id="input-height" class="form-control" />
              <?php if ($error_height) { ?>
              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_height; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-status"><?php echo $entry_status; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select name="status" id="input-status" class="form-control">
                <?php if ($status) { ?>
                <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                <option value="0"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <option value="1"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

CATALOG FILES:

CONTROLLER FILE:

```
<!-- CATALOG CONTROLLER FILE -->

<?php
class ControllerModulePopular extends Controller {
  public function index($setting) {
    $this->load->language('extension/module/popular');

    $data['heading_title']   = $this->language->get('heading_title');
    $data['text_tax']        = $this->language->get('text_tax');
    $data['button_cart']     = $this->language->get('button_cart');
    $data['button_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('button_wishlist');
    $data['button_compare']  = $this->language->get('button_compare');

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');
    $this->load->model('tool/image');

    $data['products'] = array();
    $product_data     = array();

    if(isset($setting['limit']) && $setting['limit']!=''){
      $setting['limit'] = $setting['limit'];
    }
    else{
      $setting['limit'] = 4;
    }


    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT p.product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' ORDER BY p.viewed DESC LIMIT " . (int)$setting['limit']);



    foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
      $product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($result['product_id']);
    }

    $results = $product_data;

    if ($results) {
      foreach ($results as $result) {
        if ($result['image']) {
          $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $setting['width'], $setting['height']);
        } else {
          $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $setting['width'], $setting['height']);
        }


        if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
          $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
        } else {
          $price = false;
        }

        if ((float)$result['special']) {
          $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
        } else {
          $special = false;
        }

        if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
          $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price']);
        } else {
          $tax = false;
        }


        if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
          $rating = $result['rating'];
        } else {
          $rating = false;
        }

        $data['products'][] = array(
          'product_id'   => $result['product_id'],
          'thumb'        => $image,
          'name'         => $result['name'],
          'description'  => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
          'price'        => $price,
          'special'      => $special,
          'tax'          => $tax,
          'rating'       => $rating,
          'href'         => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']),
        );
      }

      if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/extension/module/popular.tpl')) {
        return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/extension/module/popular.tpl', $data);
      } else {
        return $this->load->view('default/template/extension/module/popular.tpl', $data);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

CATALOG LANGUAGE FILE

```
<!-- LANGUAGE CONTROLLER FILE -->

<?php
// Heading
$_['heading_title'] = 'Popular Products';

// Text
$_['text_reviews']  = 'Based on %s reviews.';

// Tax
$_['text_tax']      = 'Ex Tax:';
```

CATALOG VIEW FILE

```
<!-- CATALOG VIEW FILE -->

<h3><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h3>
<div class="row">
  <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="product-thumb transition">
      <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h4><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></h4>
        <p><?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>
        <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
        <div class="rating">
          <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { ?>
          <?php if ($product['rating'] < $i) { ?>
          <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
        <p class="price">
          <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
          <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span> <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php if ($product['tax']) { ?>
          <span class="price-tax"><?php echo $text_tax; ?> <?php echo $product['tax']; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
        </p>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <div class="button-group">
        <button type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></button>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_wishlist; ?>" onclick="wishlist.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_compare; ?>" onclick="compare.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I think that covers about everything. I'm sure I have the file locations set correctly too as I know these have changed since 2.0.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, You have write wrong Controller class in both Controller files. You have forgot to mention "Extension" there.

Find and replace following code in both(ADMIN & CATALOG) controller files. and then check it.

Find:

```
class ControllerModulePopular extends Controller {
```

Replace:

```
class ControllerExtensionModulePopular extends Controller {
```

Comment: Legend. That a lack of eagle-eye on my end. Thank you.